# Adding CFBundleURLTypes to entitlements on MacOS causes Invalid Signature error if Notarization is used

Tags: macos, electron, code-signing, entitlements

I am trying to add a `CFBundleURLTypes` entry to my entitlements in order to allow deep linking to my Electron app. This works when I do not use notarisation, however, I need my app notarised and the addition of CFBundleURLTypes is causing my app to crash immediately on opening it and reporting an Invalid Signature error, even though notarisation did not actually report a failure. Is there anything else needed to allow this, for example, an entry in the provisioning profile? So far I have not seen any evidence that my configuration is incorrect and according to my research, this should work as is

`entitlements.mac.plist:`

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-jit</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-dyld-environment-variables</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.disable-library-validation</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.network.server</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.audio-input</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.device.camera</key>
    <true/>
  <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
  <array>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
    <string>my-protocol-name-here</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
    <array>
      <string>my-protocol-name-here</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: It goes in Info.plist, not your entitlements file

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue by adding the protocol inside `electron-builder` setup instead of adding directly in `entitlements.mac.plist`:

```
 protocols: {
    name: "foo",
    schemes: ["foo"]
  },
```